# Error when using CmdLet New-AzureRmADAppCredential to create new credential with certificates

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to use the New-AzureRmADAppCredential cmdlet. I am trying to create a new credential using the following syntax:

`New-SelfSignedCertificateEx -Subject "CN=$ClientId" -KeySpec "Exchange" -FriendlyName "$ClientId"
$start = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$end = $start.AddDays(4)
New-AzureRmADAppCredential -ApplicationId $application.ObjectId -CertValue $keyValue -StartDate $start -EndDate $end`

 I've noticed that if I try to create a new credential with a certificate, it failed on a specific apps with the following error: 

`New-AzureRmADAppCredential : Update to existing credential with KeyId 'keyid' is not allowed.`

This app has 2 credentials, one is a password and the other is a certificate. The keyid belong to the certificate credential. The weird part is that on other app it worked fine, even if the app has multiple certificate credentials. I've tried to look at the documentation, but couldn't find anything useful.

So, my question is - why this error happens? and how I can solve this?

Update: By looking in the [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/e97be15dd43d3e80664ce1433f72c1c1b17b0fc0/src/ResourceManager/Resources/Commands.Resources/Models.ActiveDirectory/ActiveDirectoryClient.cs) of the cmdlet, it seems like it always updating the whole list, so I think it might be something related to permission, but I am not sure.

Thanks,

Omer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, [New-AzureRmADAppCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/powershell/module/AzureRM.Resources/new-azurermadappcredential) isn't strong enough, if AAD App has keys, it will update the latest key in the key list and of course won't work(`Update to existing credential with KeyId is not allowed`), I think it's a bug; if no key existed, it will create a new key. You can use [New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential) instead.

Comment: Actually, I'm using it for a while to create new passwords (new certificates) and it works pretty well. So far, I only experienced 2 cases where it fails and it was some weird issue with Azure. And you're not totally correct. The command will get all the existing keys, add a new key to the list and send the new list to the server.

Comment: @OmerLeviHevroni PowerShell modules are updated quickly, mine is Version 5.1.1, when  AAD App has keys, New-AzureRmADAppCredential just do updating and can't work. so I used New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential instead.

Comment: `New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential` requires Connect-AzureAD to be executed first, is there any other alternative?

Comment: It took me a while, but I finally had time to test it out - and you're correct. Moving to the new CmdLet solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so we found out this happens because the first certificate was uploaded to Azure AD by modifying the application manifest. After deleting it and adding it again using powershell everything worked...