# What's the powershell command to upload certificate to AAD application?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

In Azure portal, I can create an application under AAD, navigate to "Home
(myTenant) -> App registrations -> (myApp) -> Settings -> Keys", upload public key which is a certificate to the application keys. This is easy using portal UI. But how can I do the certificate upload using Powershell command?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the command New-AzureRmADAppCredential
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadappcredential?view=azurermps-5.0.0

Example 2 in the article should work for you

----------------8<--------------------

```
$cer = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate 
$cer.Import("C:\myapp.cer") 
$binCert = $cer.GetRawCertData() 
$credValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($binCert)

New-AzureRmADAppCredential -ApplicationId 4589cd6b-3d79-4bb4-93b8-a0b99f3bfc58 -CertValue $credValue -StartDate $cer.GetEffectiveDateString() -EndDate $cer.GetExpirationDateString()
```

Answer (score 1):

**2023 Update**

For anyone reading now, when the [recommended approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/migration-steps?view=graph-powershell-1.0) in Powershell is to use the Microsoft Graph modules over Azure AD modules, the relevant commands are [Update-MgApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/update-mgapplication?view=graph-powershell-1.0) with the `-KeyCredentials` param for a new certificate or [Add-MgApplicationKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/add-mgapplicationkey?view=graph-powershell-1.0) to update an existing certificate.  (Yes, the language is confusing.  Update the app to add a key.  Add a key to update a key. And "key" actually means "public cert to validate a private key" in this case.)

Here's an example of function that pulls a cert from a keyvault and adds it to a registered AAD app:

```
function Set-AppCredential
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$AppName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$KeyVaultName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$CertificateName
    )

    $Application = Get-MgApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($AppName)'"

    $KeyVaultCertificate = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $KeyVaultName -Name $CertificateName

    $CertCredential = @{
        Type = "AsymmetricX509Cert"
        Usage = "Verify"
        Key = $KeyVaultCertificate.Certificate.RawData
    }

    Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId $Application.Id -KeyCredentials @($CertCredential)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use New-AzureRmADAppCredential to [Adds a credential to an existing Azure AD application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadappcredential?view=azurermps-5.0.0).

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$cert = New-Object    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("PATH_TO_CER_FILE")
$key = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())
New-AzureRmADAppCredential -ApplicationId d3fdf244-xxxx-xxxx-8faa-4a22b9739374  -CertValue $key
```

[image]

Comment: With this powershell cmdlet, you may not see the Thumbprint in portal, the status is THUMBPRINT is not available,but you still can use the cert to login

Comment: Thanks Wayne! Jarnstrom posted same answer earlier almost at the same time. Would like to mark yours as right answer but stackoverflow doesn't like multiple.

Comment: I am getting error saying: New-AzureRmADAppCredential : Update to existing credential with KeyId 'e65e9....94a9d84' is not allowed. Saw a similar post here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39220516/error-when-using-cmdlet-new-azurermadappcredential-to-create-new-credential-with", but the first cert was uploaded through Portal UI. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Any alternative to this, so that I can also get the thumbprint visible in the portal ?

Answer (score 0):

Building on sam256's answer, this is my version using PowerShell v7 and reading the certificate from the installed certificates on the current machine. I would love to know if there was a way to do this with fewer steps, but this is what I managed to get working.

The basic steps are:

1. Retrieve the certificate from the current machine's certificate store.

This step requires a password that is used to protect the certificate file. But Azure AD will reject a certificate that is password protected. I could not find a way to export the certificate without a password in PowerShell, even though it is possible using the Certificates UI when you don't export the private key.

2. Use the `openssl` command line utility to extract the certificate in pem format without a password.
3. Upload the PEM format of the certificate to Azure AD

Here is the code I used:

```
Write-Host "Finding the right certficate to export"
$serviceCertificates = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ | Where-Object { $_.Subject -eq "CN=$certificateName" }
$latestServiceCertificate = $serviceCertificates | Sort-Object NotAfter -desc | Select-Object -First 1

Write-Host "Exporting latest certificate with thumbprint $($latestServiceCertificate.Thumbprint)"
$plaintextPassword = "..." #TODO: Add your own plaintext password here. It is just used temporarily so you don't need to store it anywhere.
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $plaintextPassword -Force -AsPlainText
$serviceCertificateFilePath = Join-Path $certificatesPath "$certificateName.cer"
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $latestServiceCertificate -FilePath $serviceCertificateFilePath -Password $securePassword

Write-Host 'Extracting PEM file from latest certificate'
$servicePemCertificateFilePath = Join-Path $certificatesPath "$certificateName.pem"
openssl pkcs12 -in $serviceCertificateFilePath -clcerts -nokeys -password "pass:$plaintextPassword" -out $servicePemCertificateFilePath

Write-Host 'Uploading PEM file to Azure AD'
$servicePemCertificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate($servicePemCertificateFilePath)
$keyCredential = @{
    startDateTime = [System.DateTime]::UtcNow
    type = 'AsymmetricX509Cert'
    usage = 'Verify'
    key = $servicePemCertificate.GetRawCertData()
    displayName = "CN=$certificateName"
}
Connect-MgGraph
Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId $azureAdApplicationId -KeyCredentials @($keyCredential)
```